# Tensorflow read serialized data example undefined tf.FixedLenFeature

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use serialized data using the proto interface as suggested here

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files

I try to use the example : 
https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py

But it fails because :

```
In [99]: tf.FixedLenFeature
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-e5629528302a> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.FixedLenFeature

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FixedLenFeature'
```

I guess I am missing something here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of `fully_connected_reader.py` includes some (breaking) [changes to the `tf.parse_example()` API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/492e55ff2297dc13f5ed540056ad40603f2b1dd0) that were made after the TensorFlow 0.6.0 release. These changes included adding the `tf.FixedLenFeature` class as a helper for defining the schema to be used in `tf.parse_example()`. You should build TensorFlow from source or wait for the upcoming 0.7.0 release to use this version of the API.

Alternatively, the old version of the example code is available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cd53f3c3302c9312c1840389a9988a879b8b9dd5/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py), and the documentation for `tf.parse_example()` is available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#parse_example).